# How to extract information at temporary drive after PushD but use it after PopD in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to extract the file last update date and time for a specific file called settings.xml in a network directory and write it to a local log file. 
Below is what I tried.

```
PUSHD "%share%" 
forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c SET fileDate=@fDate SET fileTime=@ftime"
forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c SET fileDate=@fDate SET fileTime=@ftime"
POPD
ECHO %fileDate% %fileTime% >> "LOGFILE.TXT"
```

Where %share% is the network location and LOGFILE.TXT is on my local machine where the batch script runs. However, this only logs Echo is Off. on the log file.

I tried the following, but that wrote the information on the network drive itself, which is not what I want.

```
PUSHD "%share%" 
forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c ECHO @fDate @ftime >> LOGFILE.TXT"
POPD
```

So, how do I extract the date and time from network location, but write it to a local file? I need to store that information in a variable and later use that variable, but I just don't know how to do it. I am trying my hands on batch script for the first time.

**UPDATE 1**
Tried the following based on comments. Still not printing the time.

```
SET current=%CD%
PUSHD "%share%" 
forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c ECHO @ftime >> "%current%\LOGFILE.TXT""
POPD
```

Comment: Any variables you set using `cmd /c` with FORFILES are discarded after each file is processed.  You need to echo the date and time to your logfile as part of your `cmd /c` instance.  Is there any reason why you are not just using a `FOR /R` command with the command modifiers?

Comment: Before your `PUSHD` command, set the current directory to a variable and then use that with your logfile redirection. `set current=%CD%`  and `>>"%current%\logfile.txt"`

Comment: Why not just use the full path to the text file?

Comment: I am trying my hands on batch file for the first time. I should mention that information in the question. 
I tried what you said. Set the current directory to a variable and ECHOed it just like you mentioned. However, it does not log anything. The log file was empty. Here is what I tried
    `SET current=%CD%`

    `PUSHD "%share%"` 

    `forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c ECHO @ftime >> %current%\LOGFILE.TXT"`

    `POPD`

Comment: I am not using the full path since the script could be run from a different machine or a folder.

Comment: @sudhirvyasaraja, please update your question with any code changes. If the Current Directory has spaces in it, you need to quote the whole path plus the file name.  You did not do that in your example.  Please tag people with your responses, so that we are notified that you replied.

Comment: `forfiles /s /m settings.xml /c "cmd /c ECHO @ftime >> \"%current%\LOGFILE.TXT\""` (the inner quotes must be escaped like `\"`; alternatively you could also write `0x22` instead of `\"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to provide a solution using FOR /R instead as this is much faster.  The only caveat is that the date time modifier does not show seconds on the time.

```
FOR /R "%share%" %%G IN (settings.xml) DO echo %%~tG >>logfile.txt
```

On a side note, just wanted to prove that using `FORFILES` with the other examples works as well.

```
 @echo off
 set share=H:\
 SET current=%CD%
 PUSHD "%share%" 
 forfiles /s /m temp.txt /c "cmd /c ECHO @ftime >>"%current%\LOGFILE.TXT""
 POPD
 type logfile.txt
```

pause

output

```
 C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop>so.bat

 1:31:04 PM
 9:23:58 AM
 12:42:34 PM
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thanks Squashman! that works. Much easier than PushD and PopD. 
Could you also quickly explain what %%G and %%~tG is? that would really help me.

Comment: %%G is the FOR variable.  Just like the use of FOR in just about any language.  It needs a variable to store its execution.  The  %%~tG is a modifier asking it to give me the time of the file.  You can read all about this by reading the help for the command. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `for /?`